# Why does Object.keys() and Object.getOwnPropertyNames() produce different output when called on a Proxy object with ownKeys handler?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-proxy

I have the following proxy:

```
const p = new Proxy({}, {
  ownKeys(target) {
    return ['a', 'b'];
  },
});
```

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/ownKeys#Interceptions) says that:

> This trap can intercept these operations:
>
> - `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()`
> - `Object.getOwnPropertySymbols()`
> - `Object.keys()`
> - `Reflect.ownKeys()`

Therefore, I expected `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()` and `Object.keys()` to produce the same output. However, `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(p)` returns `['a', 'b']` (as expected), but `Object.keys(p)` returns an empty array. Why is that?

Also, if I add a property to this object which is not returned by the `ownKeys` handler (for example `c`), it gets ignored by both functions (they don't change their output). However, when I add a property which is returned by the `ownKeys` handler (for example `a`), `Object.keys(p)` now returns `['a']`.

Code snippet:

```js
const p = new Proxy({}, {
  ownKeys(target) {
    return ['a', 'b'];
  },
});

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(p)); // ['a', 'b']
console.log(Object.keys(p)); // []

p.c = true;
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(p)); // ['a', 'b']
console.log(Object.keys(p)); // []

p.a = true;
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(p)); // ['a', 'b']
console.log(Object.keys(p)); // ['a']
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The difference between [`Object.keys()`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-object.keys) and [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames()`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-object.getownpropertynames) is that [`Object.keys()` will invoke `[[GetOwnProperty]]`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-enumerableownnames) on the object, and only add the property to the result list if the returned property descriptor is *enumerable*. Since the object doesn't have a such a property, `[[GetOwnProperty]]` will return `undefined` and the property (name) is ignored.

You can overwrite/implement `[[GetOwnProperty]]` in the proxy by implementing `getOwnPropertyDescriptor`:

```js
const p = new Proxy({}, {
  ownKeys(target) {
    return ['a', 'b'];
  },
  getOwnPropertyDescriptor(k) {
    return {
      enumerable: true,
      configurable: true,
    };
  }
});

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(p)); // ['a', 'b']
console.log(Object.keys(p)); // ['a', 'b']
```

Comment: At `javascript` at Answer the values are only returned by the handlers, not set at the `target` object, yes?

Comment: No actual property appears to be set at `target` object `{}`; though `{}` does not have an identifier outside of `Proxy()` call, could use parameter of function to reference target object. The array or object are only `return`ed by function, not set at `target` `{}`?

Comment: @FelixKling so, following your line of thought one should be able to list a and b if they were defined using `Object.defneProperty` and setting it to enumerable, right? I tried that and didn't work.  Any idea why?

Answer (score 16):

The difference between `Object.keys` and `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` is that the latter returns own properties regardless of whether or not they are enumerable.

The properties added to the object by `Proxy` are non-enumerable, and won't show up in `Object.keys`, but will in `Object.getOwnPropertyNames`

Generally, properties added by assignment or a property initializer are enumerable by default, and properties added with methods such as `Object.assign`, `new Proxy` etc. are non-enumerable by default.

There's more on property ownership and enumerability on [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties), where one can also find this table that outlines the difference in the two methods

[image]

Comment: I didn't know about that table, this is great!